# Tensorflow how to sample large number of textures from small dataset of large images

Tags: tensorflow

I have 100 large-ish (1000x1000) images which I want to use as a training data set for a texture analysis system. I want to randomly generate texture swatches of about 200x200. What is the best way to do this? I would prefer to not preprocess all of the swatches so that each epoch is trained with slightly different swatches.

My initial (naive?) implementation included preprocessing layers in the model that do random crops on the image and just do a ton of epochs to accommodate the small number of large pictures, however after about ~400 epochs TF would crash without exception (it would just exit).

I now find myself coding a data generator (tf.keras.utils.Sequence) that will return a batch of swatches on request, but I feel like I'm reinventing the wheel and it is getting clunky - making me think this can't be the best way.

What is the best way to handle such a situation where you have a somewhat small dataset that you dynamically create more samples from?

Answer (score 0):

I have written a function that will segment an image. Code is below

```
import cv2
def image_segment( image_path, img_resize, crop_size):
    image_list=[]
    img=cv2.imread(image_path)
    img=cv2.resize(img, img_resize)
    shape=img.shape    
    xsteps =int( shape[0]/crop_size[0])
    ysteps = int( shape[1]/crop_size[1])  
    print (xsteps, ysteps)
    for i in range (xsteps):
        for j in range (ysteps):
            x= i * crop_size[0]
            xend=x + crop_size[0]
            y= j * crop_size[1]
            yend = y + crop_size[1]            
            cropped_image = cropped_image=img[x: xend, y: yend]
            image_list.append(cropped_image)             
    return image_list
```

below is an example of use

```
# This code provides input to the image_segment function
image_path=r'c:\temp\landscape.jpg' # location of image
width=1000 # width to resize input image
height= 800 # height to resize input image
image_resize=( width, height) # specify original image (width, height)
crop_width=200 # width of desired cropped images
crop_height=400 # height of desired cropped images
# Note to get full set of cropped images width/cropped_width and height/cropped_height should be integer values
crop_size=(crop_height, crop_width)
images=image_segment(image_path, image_resize, crop_size) # call the function
```

The code below will display the resized input image and the resultant cropped images

```
# this code will display the resized input image and the resultant cropped images
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.pyplot import imshow
img=cv2.imread(image_path) # read in the image
input_resized_image=cv2.resize(img, image_resize) # resize the image
imshow(input_resized_image) # show the resized input image
r=len(images)
plt.figure(figsize=(20, 20))
for i in range(r):    
    plt.subplot(5, 5, i + 1)
    image=images # scale images between 0 and 1 becaue pre-processor set them between -1 and +1
    plt.imshow(image[i])    
    class_name=str(i)
    plt.title(class_name, color='green', fontsize=16)
    plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```